# How to create appending writeStream in Node.js

Tags: file-io, node.js

Current documentation [here](http://nodejs.org/api.html#fs-writestream-152) doesn't seem to mention any parameters governing the stream's behaviour with regards to whether file is re-created every time or just gets data appended.

Is there a way to create a writeStream which appends the data?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is a [createWriteStream](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.0/api/fs.html#fs.createWriteStream) method right below it.

> fs.createWriteStream(path, [options])
>   Returns a new WriteStream object (See
>   Writable Stream).
>
> options is an object with the
>   following defaults:
>
> ```
> { 'flags': 'a'
> , 'encoding': null
> , 'mode': 0666
> }
> ```

Comment: flags: 'a' does it. I with the doc was clear on what are the flags available.

Comment: I assume that all C style languages inherit the same flags, here are the man pages for PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php and C++: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/.