# Node appendFile not appending data chunk to file on filesystem

Tags: node.js

I have a program that is trying to get the values from the request using curl and store them in a file and serve the stored content back. The decision to store or append the contents in file are based on a query parameter appendFlag
Now when i run this program what i am getting in **console** is "**true**" and "**appending**"  This suggests that it indeed reads the flag goes to the if part but somehow the appendFile function is not working.

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function(request,response){
    var str = request.url.split('?')[1];
    var query = querystring.parse(str);
    var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(query['fileName']);
    console.log("query - ");
    console.log(query["appendFlag"]);
    request.on('data',function(chunk){
        if(query["appendFlag"]=="true"){
            console.log("appending");
            fs.appendFile(query['fileName'],chunk.toString(),function(err){
                if(err) throw err;
            });
        }else{
            var bufferGood = writeStream.write(chunk);
            if(!bufferGood) request.pause();
        }
    });
    request.on('end',function(){
        response.writeHead(200);
        response.write("\n Content with this url is - \n");
        var readStream = fs.createReadStream(query['fileName'],{bufferSize:64*1024});
        readStream.on('data',function(chunk){
            response.write(chunk.toString());
        }); 
        readStream.on('end',function(){
            response.write("\n");
            response.end();
        });
    });
    writeStream.on('drain',function(){
        request.resume();
    });
}).listen(8080);
```

Then after reading an answer from SO( [How to create appending writeStream in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928926/how-to-create-appending-writestream-in-node-js) ) i tried -

```
// Program to extract url from the request and writing in that particular file

var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function(request,response){
    var str = request.url.split('?')[1];
    var query = querystring.parse(str);
    var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(query['fileName']);
    options = { 
        'flags': 'a' ,
        'encoding' : null,
        'mode' : 0666
    }
    var appendStream = fs.createWriteStream(query['fileName'],[options]);
    console.log("query - ");
    console.log(query["appendFlag"]);
    request.on('data',function(chunk){
        if(query["appendFlag"]=="true"){
            console.log("appending");
            var bufferGood = appendStream.write(chunk.toString());
            if(!bufferGood) request.pause();
        }else{
            var bufferGood = writeStream.write(chunk.toString());
            if(!bufferGood) request.pause();
        }
    });
    request.on('end',function(){
        response.writeHead(200);
        response.write("\n Content with this url is - \n");
        var readStream = fs.createReadStream(query['fileName'],{bufferSize:64*1024});
        readStream.on('data',function(chunk){
            response.write(chunk.toString());
        }); 
        readStream.on('end',function(){
            response.write("\n");
            response.end();
        });
    });
    writeStream.on('drain',function(){
        request.resume();
    });
}).listen(8080);
```

That is changed the flag to the '**a**' and it also did not append the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your can use your first variant. But before `appendFile()` you've opened `writeStream` for the same `query["filename"]`. The stream is already opened.

```
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(query['fileName']);
options = { 
    'flags': 'a' ,
    'encoding' : null,
    'mode' : 0666
}
var appendStream = fs.createWriteStream(query['fileName'],[options]);
```

May be it's better to do something like:

```
var options = {
  flags: query.appendFile ? 'w' : 'a'
  ...
```

Next: why `[options]`?   You should remove the brackets.

Next: there is no guarantee you'll have `filename` param in `querystring`. Please handle this situation.

Comment: Thanks, this was just a test of functionality. I am going to handle such error situations when I implement it. Also yes I wasn't able to append because I had two descriptors for one file so had to remove one and then I was good to go

Comment: Using options made me append the file correctly. I had to remove the 'mode' because the number errored, and definitely remove the brackets from options.